# Java - static variable and parameter with same name

Tags: java

Suppose I have a Helper class as below:

```
public class Helper {
    private Context context;
    private static HelperListener listener;


    public Helper(Context context, HelperListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        listener = listener; // Can't tell which one
    }
}
```

`context` and `listener` are variables that will be set only once, in the constructor.

`context` is not `static`, hence I can differentiate the variable from the parameter using `this.context`.

`listener`, on the other hand, is `static`. Is there any way to differentiate it from the parameter when it comes to static variables?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `Helper.listener = listener;` although setting the value of a static variable from a constructor is not recommended.

Comment: Could you please explain briefly why it is not recommended?

Comment: It's not necessarily bad practice. It depends on what you're trying to do (e.g. sometimes you may want to keep an instantiation count by updating a static variable in the constructor).

Comment: As arshajii said, it is not bad practice, but... static variables are independent of object instances and constructors are called when objects are created. So every time you create an Object, the static variable is set although its value is not related to the object being created.

Answer (score 16):

You can qualify the static variable with the class name to differentiate it:

```
Helper.listener = listener;
```

Comment: Why not this.listener = listener ;

Comment: @SurajJain Not sure about this but: In this case that would work cause that class can be instanced (it's not static) and we would be doing this in the constructor (or non static method). However that wouldn't work inside a static method (who is this?). Thus I would stick with suggested answers and use the class name to differentiate members from parameters for the sake of clarity and sanity :)